# javascript confliction in 1 page with click on checkbox

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

When i click on `<thead>` checkbox of first `Table` so checked also 2nd `Table` checkbox. but it's not that i am need. when i click on First thead checkbox so it will all checked of first Table.

and i also need to on click `File-Name.mp4` to go on url link path. but when i remove `e.preventDefault();` so checkbox not working.

i am trying but giving error in First Table too.. :(

```js
$('.dashboard-table-tbody tr').click(function(e) {

  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).children('td').children('div').children('input').prop('checked', false);
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).children('td').children('div').children('input').prop('checked', true);
  }

  if ($('.table tbody').find('input:checkbox:checked').length === $('.table tbody').find('input:checkbox').length) {
    $(".headerCheckbox").prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $(".headerCheckbox").prop('checked', false);
  }
  e.preventDefault();

});

$(".headerCheckbox").click(function(e) {

  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(".table tbody tr").addClass("active");
    $(".table tbody tr input:checkbox").prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $(".table tbody tr").removeClass("active");
    $(".table tbody tr input:checkbox").prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

```css
.dashboard-table-responsive {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 23px #eeeff1;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.dashboard-table {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 15px;
  color: #8b8e8c;
}

.dashboard-table th {
  border: none;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.dashboard-table td {
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.dashboard-table a {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.table-checkbox-col-head {
  width: 44px;
}

.table-checkbox {
  padding: 0;
  min-height: auto;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.table-checkbox .table-checkbox-label {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}

.table-checkbox .table-checkbox-label:before,
.table-checkbox .table-checkbox-label:after {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.dashboard-table tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #fafbfe;
  cursor: default;
}

.dashboard-table tbody tr.active {
  background-color: #f8f9fc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="table-responsive dashboard-table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-sm dashboard-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="table-checkbox-col-head">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
                <input class="custom-control-input headerCheckbox" id="customControlInline2" type="checkbox">
                <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline2"></label>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="p-l-0">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Size</th>
            <th scope="col">Upload at</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-right">Views</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="dashboard-table-tbody">
          <tr>
            <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
                <input class="custom-control-input checkBox" id="customControlInline3" type="checkbox">
                <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline3"></label>
              </div>
              </th>
              <td class="p-l-0"><a href="https://www.nexshot.io">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
              <td>137.3kB</td>
              <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
              <td class="text-right">10</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="active">
            <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
                <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline4" type="checkbox" checked>
                <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline4"></label>
              </div>
              </th>
              <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
              <td>137.3kB</td>
              <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
              <td class="text-right">10</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
                <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline5" type="checkbox">
                <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline5"></label>
              </div>
              </th>
              <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
              <td>137.3kB</td>
              <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
              <td class="text-right">10</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
                <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline6" type="checkbox">
                <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline6"></label>
              </div>
              </th>
              <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
              <td>137.3kB</td>
              <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
              <td class="text-right">10</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
                <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline7" type="checkbox">
                <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline7"></label>
              </div>
              </th>
              <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
              <td>137.3kB</td>
              <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
              <td class="text-right">10</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
                <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline8" type="checkbox">
                <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline8"></label>
              </div>
              </th>
              <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
              <td>137.3kB</td>
              <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
              <td class="text-right">10</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">

    <div class="table-responsive dashboard-table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-sm dashboard-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="table-checkbox-col-head">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
                <input class="custom-control-input headerCheckbox" id="customControlInline321" type="checkbox">
                <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline321"></label>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="p-l-0">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Size</th>
            <th scope="col">Upload at</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-right">Views</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="dashboard-table-tbody">
          <tr>
            <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
                <input class="custom-control-input checkBox" id="customControlInline398" type="checkbox">
                <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline398"></label>
              </div>
              </th>
              <td class="p-l-0"><a href="https://www.nexshot.io">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
              <td>137.3kB</td>
              <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
              <td class="text-right">10</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="active">
            <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
                <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline544" type="checkbox">
                <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline544"></label>
              </div>
              </th>
              <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
              <td>137.3kB</td>
              <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
              <td class="text-right">10</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
                <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline536541065" type="checkbox">
                <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline536541065"></label>
              </div>
              </th>
              <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
              <td>137.3kB</td>
              <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
              <td class="text-right">10</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
                <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline636" type="checkbox">
                <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline636"></label>
              </div>
              </th>
              <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
              <td>137.3kB</td>
              <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
              <td class="text-right">10</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
                <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline987" type="checkbox">
                <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline987"></label>
              </div>
              </th>
              <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
              <td>137.3kB</td>
              <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
              <td class="text-right">10</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
                <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline898" type="checkbox">
                <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline898"></label>
              </div>
              </th>
              <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
              <td>137.3kB</td>
              <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
              <td class="text-right">10</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please try to reword this as your intent is not very clear.  I do realize that English is  probably not your first language but please do try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make the assumption that you want:

1. If the table header checkbox is checked, check all the child rows checkbox
2. If any of the children are checked, make the header checked if all children are checked
3. Do this on a table by table basis

This can probably be simplified but for now it should work

```js
$('.dashboard-table-tbody').on('click', 'tr', function(e) {
  var thisTRow = $(this);
  var isActive = !!thisTRow.hasClass('active');
  thisTRow.toggleClass('active', !isActive);
  var rowChecks =
    thisTRow.find('input[type=checkbox]')
    .prop('checked', !isActive);
  var thisTBody = $(e.delegateTarget);
  var thisTable = thisTBody.closest('table.table');
  var allChecks = thisTBody.find('input[type=checkbox]');
  var allAreChecked = allChecks.filter(function() {
    return $(this).is(':checked');
  }).length === allChecks.length;
  var thCheck = thisTable.find(".headerCheckbox");
  thCheck.prop('checked', allAreChecked);

  e.preventDefault();
});
// image click
$('.dashboard-table-tbody').on('click', 'td.p-l-0 a', function(e) {
  // just follow the link, not propagate to the tr
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$('.table').on('click change', ".headerCheckbox", function(e) {
  var thisTable = $(e.delegateTarget);
  var headerChecked = $(this)[0].checked;
  thisTable.find(".dashboard-table-tbody")
    .find('tr').toggleClass("active", headerChecked);
  thisTable.find("input:checkbox").prop('checked', headerChecked);

});
```

```css
.dashboard-table-responsive {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 23px #eeeff1;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.dashboard-table {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 15px;
  color: #8b8e8c;
}

.dashboard-table th {
  border: none;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.dashboard-table td {
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.dashboard-table a {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.table-checkbox-col-head {
  width: 44px;
}

.table-checkbox {
  padding: 0;
  min-height: auto;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.table-checkbox .table-checkbox-label {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}

.table-checkbox .table-checkbox-label:before,
.table-checkbox .table-checkbox-label:after {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.dashboard-table tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #fafbfe;
  cursor: default;
}

.dashboard-table tbody tr.active {
  background-color: #f8f9fc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="table-responsive dashboard-table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-sm dashboard-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="table-checkbox-col-head">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
                <input class="custom-control-input headerCheckbox" id="customControlInline2" type="checkbox">
                <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline2"></label>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="p-l-0">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Size</th>
            <th scope="col">Upload at</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-right">Views</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="dashboard-table-tbody">
          <tr>
            <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
                <input class="custom-control-input checkBox" id="customControlInline3" type="checkbox">
                <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline3"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="p-l-0"><a href="https://www.nexshot.io">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
            <td>137.3kB</td>
            <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
            <td class="text-right">10</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="active">
            <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
                <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline4" type="checkbox" checked>
                <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline4"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
            <td>137.3kB</td>
            <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
            <td class="text-right">10</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
                <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline5" type="checkbox">
                <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline5"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
            <td>137.3kB</td>
            <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
            <td class="text-right">10</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
                <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline6" type="checkbox">
                <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline6"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
            <td>137.3kB</td>
            <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
            <td class="text-right">10</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
                <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline7" type="checkbox">
                <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline7"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
            <td>137.3kB</td>
            <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
            <td class="text-right">10</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
                <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline8" type="checkbox">
                <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline8"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
            <td>137.3kB</td>
            <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
            <td class="text-right">10</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">

    <div class="table-responsive dashboard-table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-sm dashboard-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="table-checkbox-col-head">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
                <input class="custom-control-input headerCheckbox" id="customControlInline321" type="checkbox">
                <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline321"></label>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="p-l-0">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Size</th>
            <th scope="col">Upload at</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-right">Views</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="dashboard-table-tbody">
          <tr>
            <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
                <input class="custom-control-input checkBox" id="customControlInline398" type="checkbox">
                <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline398"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="p-l-0"><a href="https://www.nexshot.io">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
            <td>137.3kB</td>
            <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
            <td class="text-right">10</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="active">
            <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
                <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline544" type="checkbox">
                <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline544"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
            <td>137.3kB</td>
            <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
            <td class="text-right">10</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
                <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline536541065" type="checkbox">
                <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline536541065"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
            <td>137.3kB</td>
            <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
            <td class="text-right">10</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
                <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline636" type="checkbox">
                <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline636"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
            <td>137.3kB</td>
            <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
            <td class="text-right">10</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
                <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline987" type="checkbox">
                <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline987"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
            <td>137.3kB</td>
            <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
            <td class="text-right">10</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
                <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline898" type="checkbox">
                <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline898"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
            <td>137.3kB</td>
            <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
            <td class="text-right">10</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: almost done, just 1 thing. when we click on File-Name.mp4 so open the link instead of checkbox checked.

Comment: You had some bad `th` close on the `td` in the body so I fixed that. Not all of your `a` links have a proper URL and only have `#` but for those that do, I added a click handler and stopped the propagation to the `tr` (really that is a NEW question, but easy to do here.